# Windows key not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

All of a sudden my Windows key is not working (the usual "I didn't change anything" disclaimer applies).

- I have two Windows accounts, one for me, one for admin. The problem occurs with both
- I suspected that something was software mapping the key, so checked that Gaming mode was off, etc). The problem still occurs
- I rolled back to a restore point last week. The problem still occurs
- I finally thought to attach an external USB keyboard to my laptop - it's Windows key works  !

So, it looks like a pure hardware problem, alas.

I use primarily hotkeys, rather than mouse or menu so this is a big problem.

I can only think to map another key to the Windows key, so I tried MS Power Toys and a few other key mappers. None of them work, even after reboot (which I cannot understand).

Other than being without my laptop for three weeks while the keyboard is being replaced, what are my options?

---

[Update] as per comments, Auto Hot Key detects all key presses ***except*** the left Windows key.

Also,  I popped the key cap. It looks ok, no gunge or obstruction, and pressing the switch which is revealed does nothing.

Comment: Does `CTRL` + `ESC` work?

Comment: Pull the keycap and check if there is any dirt or something broken off

Comment: Use something like [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/)'s [keyboardhook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm) to check for sure there's no activity coming from the key?

Comment: Ctr-Esc works (although I currently use to for something). I would rather not remove the keycap, but have slid a thin knife behind it & find no obstruction. I will look into AKH (fortunately I am a programmer). Thanks all

Comment: @Arctiic an AHK script containing `#InstallKeybdHook
KeyHistory` shows all other key presses, but not the left Windows key. Looks like it is physically dead :-(

Comment: @mashuptwice since it can't get any more broken, I popped the key cap. It looks ok, no gunge or obstruction, and pressing the switch which is revealed does nothing :-(

Comment: Is it one of those keyboards which have a "gaming mode" _at the keyboard level_? I distinctly remember an earlier question where the keyboard turned out to have a whole dedicated button for enabling/disabling the Win key, and I think I've also seen one where it was a Fn+ combination to deactivate it.

Comment: In PowerShell, enter `[System.Console]::ReadKey()`. then press the left Windows key.  Is it registering a key press event?

Comment: It's a modifier, so has to be pressed in combination with another key, just like Alt, Ctrl, Shift.  No, if is not seen, so I guess that it's a hardware fault. Thanks for the help

Comment: Open the on-screen keyboard app and hold down the windows key. Does it highlight? Then try again with your other keyboard. Does it highlight? Now move your "faulty" keyboard to another windows computer and perform the same tests. This should isolate it down to a hardware issue.

Comment: so autohotkey can't map either I guess?

Comment: Too late now. I had the keyboard replaced

Answer (score 4):

Often gamer-focused keyboards and laptops have a way to disable the Windows key, to avoid accidental presses which would switch out of a full screen game and serve no other purpose in-game. Usually this feature is toggled on and off by an Fn-key combination indicated on the keyboard by a lock symbol

- Fn+Win is common on generic mechanical keyboards
- Fn+F12 is used on some HP Omen laptops

Double check if your keyboard appears to have this feature and if so try toggling it.

Many wired generic mechanical keyboards with this feature will forget the state of the lock when they lose power, so if disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard makes the Windows key work again, consider whether you're somehow activating a lock feature accidentally.

In the absence of a dedicated keyboard function like that, some gaming-oriented systems will come with preinstalled software that provides this feature in software and is configurable through the UI. Check the "system tray" for any extra software that would provide this feature, such as MSI's Dragon Center.

(To make sure you're seeing all "system tray" icons, right click the Taskbar, choose Taskbar Settings, click on the link "Select which icons appear on the taskbar"; you can use the sliders there to enable any icons you need to interact with)

Comment: Thanks, it was the Omen key lock